# How to exclude null values from being pushed into an array?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-ads-api

I'm trying to do something which I thought would be extremely simple but is baffling me for some reason: I've got a function that's pushing a bunch of IDs of locations into an array and I don't want it to push these values in if they're null (the script allows user input from a Google Sheet so it's possible they'll input an incorrect value that won't get matched to an ID).

I've tried this so far:

```
    for (var i = 0; i <= startEndDifference; i++) {
      if (objectLocationInputStart != null) {
        objectLocationIdsArray.push(locationMatch(objectLocationInputStart));
      }
      objectLocationInputStart = objectLocationInputStart + 1
    }
```

but null values are still pushing to the array.

For context, this is referring to two cells in a Google sheet with a starting number and an ending number, and the for loop picks up all the numbers in between and matches them to an ID using the function. Everything it does is working perfectly other than passing in the null values.

Comment: It looks like the `locationMatch(objectLocationInputStart)` is the value you're pushing, so if the value needs to be not null, you need to test that value against null: `locationMatch(objectLocationInputStart) !== null`

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I knew it was something really stupid I was missing - been staring at this whole thing for way too long!